# Method that takes an array and moves all of the zeros to the end, preserving the order of the other elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, push, splice

I am trying to understand why this part -- `arr.splice(index, 1).push(0)` -- of my code is not working. 
why can't I splice and then push?

```
var moveZeros = function (arr) { 
  const newArray = arr.map((element, index) => element === 0 ? arr.splice(index, 1).push(element) : console.log(index, element))
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Array.splice() returns an array of the elements that are removed from the array on which splice() was called on. Find documentation here:
[Array.splice() documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

You can achieve your goal by following code snippet:

```
let arr = [1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]

var moveZeros = function (arr) {
    let zeroes = [];
    let a = arr.reduce((finalArray, element) => {
        element === 0 ? zeroes.push(element) : finalArray.push(element)
        return finalArray;
    }, []);
    return [...a, ...zeroes];
}

console.log(moveZeros(arr));
```

Answer (score 3):

`splice` returns an array of the removed elements. If you do

```
arr.splice(index, 1).push(0)
```

then you're pushing to the array of removed zeros (and that expression is subsequently discarded immediately afterwards).

You also shouldn't mutate an array while iterating over it - that'll make for very confusing behavior.

Consider filtering out zeros, while pushing to an array of zeros instead, and then combine the two arrays afterwards:

```js
const moveZeros = (arr) => {
  const zeros = [];
  return arr
    .filter((elm) => {
      if (elm === 0) {
        zeros.push(0);
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    })
    .concat(zeros);
};

console.log(moveZeros([0, 1, 2, 3]));
console.log(moveZeros([3, 2, 1,0, 1, 2, 3]));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a sorting instead and move all zeroes to the end. This approach rely on modern user agents which keep a stable sorting for equal (the onces whoes callback return zero) elements.

```js
var array = [0, 1, 9, 2, 0, 0, 3, 5, 4, 2];

array.sort((a, b) => !a - !b);

console.log(array)
```